# jQuery UI Accordion Is Choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the accordion function built in to the jQuery UI. It works fine, but the animation is very choppy, I can't seem to figure out why. I've looked at other answers on here, and none have worked so far.

jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({ animate: true },{ heightStyle: "content" });
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class ='accordion'>
<li>
    <h3><!-- heading --></h3>
    <p><!-- content --></p>
</li>
<li>
    <h3><!-- heading --></h3>
    <p><!-- content --></p>
</li>
<li>
    <h3><!-- heading --></h3>
    <p><!-- content --></p>
</li>
</ul>
```

All this markup and code is contained in the same HTML file.

Comment: What do you mean by choppy?

Comment: I took the options you specified out, and it made it much faster. http://jsfiddle.net/TZYXq/ Are those options necessary?

Comment: When opening a section, the animation is not smooth like the [example](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) provided by jQuery. It instead will open and cause the elements below it to jump downward and then back into place after the animation has completed.

Comment: @Gray I tried your suggestion and it continues. It's very weird.

Comment: @anater The bottom one is just like yours... Does the top list also have the problem for you? The first one is significantly smoother for me.

Comment: @Gray I'm guessing that it may have to do with the styling on the elements. Both run smoothly compared to what's going on on this page. From what I can tell, the default styling constrains the whole accordion to one height and that seems to prevent it from affecting other elements on the page. I am not using the default styles (nor have I explicitly overridden them). But the problem seems to be that the elements below the accordion are jumping around while the animation happens, which is causing the "choppy" look.

Comment: @anater Would it be possible to post your actual HTML (or something close)? Also, if you can, maybe make a jsfiddle that showcases the problem you are having. That will make things easier to debug.

Comment: Live site: http://naterlaw.com/practice.html @Gray

Comment: @anater - I was really thinking more along the lines of putting your HTML on this page so that it will benefit future readers as well as provide a resource for people answering without having to go to some stranger's site.

Answer (score -1):

It probably depends on what browser you are on. Many jQuery UI animations in IE8 and below are very 'choppy'.

Comment: I'm using the most recent of Chrome to test this. I'm pretty sure the browser or system aren't causing the limitations. It's persistent through Safari and Firefox as well.